# updating value of an object in a list of objects

Tags: java, java-8

I have to update a field of an object in a list of object

I have a class "Book"

```
class Book{
   String name ;
   int count;
  ....constructor
  .. getter setters
}
```

now I have a method updateCount

```
public void updateCount() {
  List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>() {
   {
     add(new Book("Book1", 1));
     add(new Book("Book2" , 2));

     // it can be more than 2 and in any manner not in any defined sequence  but we can
     // identify with the book name
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   /// now i have to update the value of count to 3 in book2
   /// how can I update
}
```

If anyone have solution using java 8. it would be great

Comment: Do you mean you want to add new Book object in the existing list of Book?

Comment: no i just want to update the count of book2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter on the streamed list, then simply update the count

```
public void updateCount(String bookName, int updateBy) {
  books.stream().filter(book -> book.getName().equals(bookName)).forEach(
      book -> book.setCount(book.getCount() + updateBy)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through list like following and for updating object value you can provide condition or use Index of the array as per your need. suppose you need to update a book which is having price 100 to 7500, you can do following.

```
for (Book book : books){
  if( book.getPrice() == 100){
       book.setPrice(7500);
  }
}

// if you want to update the book2's number, then
for (Book book: books){
  if( book.getName() == "Book2"){
      book.setNumber(/*set number here*/);
  }
}
```

Comment: if there is a hundred no. of entry then what you think this will be a good solution??

Comment: It's linear search, and this is a basic method by which you can update value. if you want to search the value then you can use hashmap, this will be best solution for that kind of practice. time complexity will be reduced to O(1) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
books.stream().filter(book -> book.getName().equals("book2")).findFirst().get().setCount(3);
```

However it will throw `NoSuchElementException` if book2 will not exist in List.
That's why you should use `Optional.isPresent()` check.

```
Optional<Book> book2 = books.stream().filter(book -> book.getName().equals("book2")).findFirst();
book2.ifPresent(book -> book.setCount(3));
```

Notice that I am looking also only for the first found `book2`. If you want to find all `Book` with specific name you should use `foreach` syntax instead of `findFirst`.

Answer (score 0):

The `updateCount` method you linked just seems to create a list of books, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but perhaps that method should return `List<Book>` so that you can create a list of books in your main function? If you do that then you can create a new method where you can pass it your list, the index you want to update in that list and the new count value for that book, something like this:

```
private void updateBookCount(List<Book> books, int booksIndex, int newCount)
{
     if (books.size() > booksIndex)
         books.get(booksIndex).setCount(newCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and crisp way to do it:

```
public void updateCount(List<Book> books) {
    books.stream()
         .filter(book -> book.getName().equals("book2"))
         .findFirst()
         .get()
         .setCount(3);
}
```